# Installing Composer in PHP with cPanel

Tags: composer-php

I want to add an "Sign in with Google" button on my webapp. At one part of it, I am being asked to install composer.

Install Composer:

curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Now, how do I execute this command on my server from cPanel?

I am new to all this, is there any step by step instructions anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

Where do you have the code that builds your website? I suspect you have the code elsewhere and upload it. That machine is the one to install Composer on, and execute all the commands needed to integrate that other package.

After you ran something like `composer install` or `composer update` (substitute "composer" with whatever executes that PHP script, like `composer.phar` or `php composer.phar` or `c:\PHP\php.exe composer` - it depends on how PHP is installed there), you simply upload the result to your server as usual.